# What can replace vitamio?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I integrated vitamio but does not work properly.
I tested the Snapdragon 801 works properly
In Snapdragon 805, the same work properly
In February zenfone ASUS Intel CPU begins decoding but not start anything. Screen remains black.
The nexus player, intel cpu 64, again the screen remains blank.
In nvidia shield tv, cpu nvidia x1, vitamio works but does not go m3u8.
the nexus 9 cpu nvidia k1 again give erroare m3u8.

My question is: what can replace vitamio? and if there is a tutorial, I have great knowledge.